# Using javascript to pass web forms values to python script

Tags: javascript, python, ssl, x509certificate

**What I have done:**

1- Created a web form using HTML and javascript to create a SSL certificate that can create dynamic certificates.

2- Successfully parsed through an existing certificate and passed the required values to the web form.

3- I am using the HTML+javascript inside the python script itself and appending the parsed certificate values to the javascript before displaying it.

**What I need to do:**

1-Take values from the web form, assign those to particular variables and pass those variables to a python script, that can create a CSR using those and sign it using a dummy key.
So, basically, I want to call a python script on a click of a button that can take web form values and create a certificate.

P.S. PHP isn't an option for me, as the server I am working on doesn't support it.
Can someone guide me in the right direction as for how to proceed? Any examples or study material? Or should I start working with Flask?

Comment: Flask is a perfectly reasonable answer to this issue.

Comment: Do you any example in mind that I can use to learn better?

Comment: The tutorials are always a good place to start; http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/

Comment: The server I am working in doesn't support the command app.run(), which in my knowledge is essential for flask to be running. So, is there any other way around this or any other tool that I should be looking at?

Comment: Have you [installed flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/installation/)?

Comment: I am executing the script directly through opening it in a new tab. Anyway, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Django is a good option to create applications using python. You can start an application, and embed your code in template and write a view to handle requests and responses.